# How to standardize strings in R

Tags: r, string

I have a series of files from different time periods.  These data have similar column names, but differences in how the values are formatted.

```
a <- c("123-OldStyle", "123.Old Style", "(123) Old Style"))
```

I can do this manually with a `dplyr::recode`, I suppose, but I can't get this recode to work with a vector.

```
dplyr::recode(a, "123-OldStyle" = "123 New Style")

vec_recode <- c("123-OldStyle" = "123 New Style", "123.Old Style" = "123 New Style", "(123) Old Style" = "123 New Style"))
```

I could do this with a long `ifelse`, but I'd rather not do this all manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `!!!` on a named vector with the `recode` to convert it to `New Style`

```
dplyr::recode(a, !!! vec_recode)
```

-output

```
#[1] "123 New Style" "123 New Style" "123 New Style"
```

---

Also, in `base R`, we can just do the matching with `[` as we have a named vector

```
unname(vec_recode[a])
#[1] "123 New Style" "123 New Style" "123 New Style"
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also clean the string in this way:

```
#Code
gsub('OldStyle','Old Style',gsub('[[:punct:] ]+',' ',a))
```

Output:

```
[1] "123 Old Style"  "123 Old Style"  " 123 Old Style"
```